# local broadcast is displayed on "onion circuits"?

Tags: whonix

When I'm using whonix,
I frequently see ip address 255.255.255.255:443 on "onion circuits".
Why is local braodcast is displayed as tor destination ?
And this address remains even after I close my browser.
I've never seen this address on "onion circuits" ,when I'm using tails or other distros with tbb and "onion circuits".
This happens in both qubes-whonix and normal whonix.

Comment: Can you provide more information like logs?

Comment: It seems that message "Have tried resolving or connecting to address '[scrubbed]' at 3 different places. Giving up." appears on nyx,when 255.255.255.255:443s are displayed as destination on onion-circuits.

According to https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/5580
This message seems 
"DNS resolution failed for some server host. Could happen."

Does this have something to do with tor destination 255.255.255.255:443 on onion-circuits?
And why only whonix?